# Recursive min-heap error?

Tags: c++, c, data-structures

I wrote the following code for constructing a min heap .. it is a recursive call. I dont know where am I going wrong as the output is not a minheap..can someone please help me with this:

```
 void MinHeap(int root, int bottom)
 {
 int parent;
 int temp;

 if(bottom > root)
 {
      parent = (bottom -1) / 2;
      if(HeapArray[parent] > HeapArray[bottom])
      {
           temp = HeapArray[parent];
           HeapArray[parent] = HeapArray[bottom];
           HeapArray[bottom] = temp;
           MinHeap(root, parent);
      }else if (HeapArray[parent] > HeapArray[bottom-1])
      {
           temp = HeapArray[parent];
           HeapArray[parent] = HeapArray[bottom-1];
           HeapArray[bottom-1] = temp;
           MinHeap(root, parent);              
      }
 } }
```

For example I am getting the following min_heap:

1935, 1952, 1940, 1998, 1962

This is clearly not a min_heap due to 1952, 1998.

Comment: 1952 is less than 1998, as you would expect in a min-heap. Your output seems fine to me.

Comment: 1952 and 1940 are both greater than 1935. 1998 and 1962 are both greater than 1952.  Seems like it's working just fine.

Comment: You do say that you are using this to build a min-heap.  You must execute this code for each of the leaves for it to work correctly.  When you insert an item into the heap you only need to perform it on the item that you inserted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code looks fine and what you're getting is a min binary heap array-compacted representation.

You can interpret the data you're obtaining as follows:

```
1935, 1952, 1940,    1998,  1962
root--child1
    |    |---------- child1
    |    |------------------child2
    |-------child2
```

and since the rules for a minimum heap are:

> - The tree is a complete binary tree; that is, all levels of the tree, except possibly the last one (deepest) are fully filled, and, if the
>     last level of the tree is not complete, the nodes of that level are
>     filled from left to right.
> - All nodes are either [greater than or equal to] or [less than or equal to] each of its children, according to a comparison predicate
>     defined for the heap.

(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap)

the code is computing the minimum heap correctly. There isn't much information in your question but for what you just posted (and from the code), looks correct.